# display none style get added dynamically on element on click jquery issue

Tags: jquery

When I click on menu item style="display:none" get added dynamicaly in element 
for eg:

```
<li class="add-cart-button btn-group" style="display: none;">
-----------------------------
</li>
```

as a result my menu item get removed.

This is an issue of jquery script in magento.

What should I do so that on click 'style="display: none;"' does not get added

Comment: May be there is some jquery code present by which the css changes dynamically

Comment: see to it from where your li getting style as display none but as a solution you can give li element as css display block

Answer (score 0):

Please check css for this class.if css contains display: none; then overwrite this css.

```
.add-cart-button{ display: block; !important}
```